# How to avoid a ß typed when capturing ALT+S with javascript?

Tags: javascript, macos

I'm using [this](https://stackoverflow.com/a/5235968/303295) method for capturing key combos.

Most of them work as expected but, at least on Chrome on OS X, when capturing ALT+S (key codes 18 + 83) the char ß gets typed into the browser - which is disruptive.

How can I prevent that char from being typed?

Comment: Suggestion: Avoid alt+letter hotkeys, because they make it hard to type with a keyboard layout that relies on those. Polish keyboards have a lot of them it's a pain to keep triggering hotkeys during typing

Comment: @Mohsen preventDefault seems to do the trick - thanks!